# KD App does not build, undefined referance to Solid libs

Tags: c++, qt, kde-plasma, undefined-reference, kdevelop

I am trying to build some KDE software I am writing in KDevelop but am getting these errors:

```
CMakeFiles/kquickformat.dir/deviceinfo.o: In function `QList<Solid::Device>::node_destruct(QList<Solid::Device>::Node*, QList<Solid::Device>::Node*)':
/usr/include/QtCore/qlist.h:418: undefined reference to `Solid::Device::~Device()'
CMakeFiles/kquickformat.dir/deviceinfo.o: In function `DeviceInfo':
/home/kemra102/projects/KDE/kquickformat/src/deviceinfo.cpp:5: undefined reference to `Solid::DeviceNotifier::instance()'
/home/kemra102/projects/KDE/kquickformat/src/deviceinfo.cpp:7: undefined reference to `Solid::Device::listFromType(Solid::DeviceInterface::Type const&, QString const&)'
CMakeFiles/kquickformat.dir/deviceinfo.o: In function `DeviceNotifier':
/usr/include/KDE/Solid/../../solid/devicenotifier.h:42: undefined reference to `vtable for Solid::DeviceNotifier'
CMakeFiles/kquickformat.dir/deviceinfo.o: In function `~DeviceNotifier':
/usr/include/KDE/Solid/../../solid/devicenotifier.h:42: undefined reference to `vtable for Solid::DeviceNotifier'
```

The relevant code is as follows:

```
#include "deviceinfo.h"

DeviceInfo::DeviceInfo(Solid::DeviceNotifier *parent)
{
  Solid::DeviceNotifier *notifier = Solid::DeviceNotifier::instance();

  QList<Solid::Device> list =  Solid::Device::listFromType(Solid::DeviceInterface::StorageDrive, QString());
}
```

and

```
#ifndef DEVICEINFO_H
#define DEVICEINFO_H

#include <QList>
#include <QString>
#include <Solid/Device>
#include <Solid/DeviceNotifier>
#include <Solid/StorageDrive>

class DeviceInfo : public Solid::DeviceNotifier
{
  public:


  private:
    DeviceInfo(Solid::DeviceNotifier *parent=0);
    Solid::DeviceNotifier* notifier;
    QList<Solid::Device> list;
};

#endif
```

I definitely have the libraries installed and can see them on my file system, so I cannot understand why Kdevelop refuses to build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tell CMake to link those libraries? I believe you can use the "${SOLID_LIBS}" var, like so:

```
target_link_libraries(... ${SOLID_LIBS} ...)
```

Comment: Apparently it's ${KED4_SOLID_LIBS} that's required. I haven't seen this noted anywhere in any documentation - do you know if it's listed online anywhere?

Comment: Some documentation: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries#How_package_finding_works
  
Properly, your CMake build system should probably do the full find_package/if (FOUND)/Libs/Inc Dirs.